# Javascript replace substring doesn't work well if the string repeats

Tags: javascript, replace, substring, slice, substr

I have a quite simple problem with substring/substr/slice. My code is very complicated so I won't post it here, but here is the simplified version of the problem:

For example how to change text.substring(5, 10) to "Something"?

```
text = "HelloHello";
```

if I try

```
text = text.replace(text.substring(5,10), "Something");
```

the result will be "SomethingHello", because text.substring(0, 5) was also "Hello", but I want to get "HelloSomething"

It doesn't work with slice() and substr() either, can you show me a solution?

Comment: What's wrong with `text = text.substring(0,5) + "Something";`?

Comment: well, my code is complicated, but the real question is: how to replace the string between the characters text[a] and text[b], if the string already appeared in the text before?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace *all* of the text between two index values with some other text, or that you want to search within the substring specified by two index values and do a replacement within that substring only? I can think of two ways to do it where it doesn't matter whether the search string appears outside the specified range.

Comment: I want to replace all of the text between the two index.

Comment: OK. Well that *is* possible with the replace() method, but it would be simpler to just do `text = text.substring(0, start) + "Something" + text.substring(end);`.

Comment: @nnnnnn wow :D I think this will be the simpliest answer to my question, thank you :)

Comment: @aikich That answer is the same (essentially) as semansers. You should go with rockerest's solution if you are treating it as a string, and mine if it is an HTML element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments below, I have wrote function `replacePartOfText()`.

This function replace all of the text to word between the two index (start, end)

```js
text = "HelloHello"

function replacePartOfText(text, start, end, word) {
  result = text.substring(0, start) + word + text.substring(end, text.length)

  return result
}

text = replacePartOfText(text, 5, 10, "Something")

console.log(text) // "HelloSomething"
```

Comment: This won't give `HelloSomething`. It will replace all occurrence.

Comment: The truth is, that I want to replace the string based on the numbers 5 and 10.
For example how would you replace the 4th Hello here:

HelloHello
Hello

Hello
Hello

Comment: @ArunGhosh - It certainly won't replace all occurrences. A regex replace only replaces all occurrences if you specify the global flag, but in any case this particular regex only matches that word if it appears at the end of the string, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn I missed the `$`. But still it is not what the question asked for. It has substring from based on position and it is missing here.

Comment: @ArunGhosh check function above. I have changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you guys, you were fast! :)

Comment: How does this work with whitespace at the beginning or end?

Comment: @semanser Is that as expected, though? If manipulating DOM elements, for example, you might want to skip over that whitespace.

Comment: @Martin but we are not working with DOM elements now, so all we need to respect ALL characters in the string (even spaces).

Comment: @semanser Actually, you don't know this use case isn't for DOM elements. If we are handling it as a string solely, then rockerest has a far better solution than ours.

Comment: @Martin see my comment below his answer. Functionality is good, but what if someone need to reuse this not only for one piece of code?

Comment: Then wrap it in a function anyway. Regardless, his use of splice is much closer to intended functionality

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead of all these convoluted solutions?

```js
var chars = "HelloHelloHello Hello HelloHello".split( "" );

chars.splice( 16, 5, "Something" );

alert( chars.join( "" ) );
```

Clear functionality, readability, and maintainability will always win, and this is just about as obvious as you can get.

Comment: this is ok, but what if I need to reuse this functionality not only for `chars`? I think function is more general solution.

Comment: Yes the functions are a core part of JavaScript. They're named `split`, `splice`, and `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "HelloHelloMahamadali.It is working now.";
var textbefore = text.substring(0,5);
var textafter = text.substring(5,text.length);
var texttoreplace = "Hello";
text = textbefore + textafter.replace(texttoreplace, "Something");
alert(text);
```

Please use above one logic , i hope this will help you. Thanks. feel free to comment.

Comment: Can you please vote this answer as positive if it worked for you please.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, so my upvote doesn't count :/ I am a new user here

Answer (score 0):

## Firstly, to get it to work:

To satisfy this need:

> "how to replace the string between the characters text[a] and text[b]"

```
function replaceStringPortion(text, start, end, replacement, trim) {
  text = !!trim ? text.trim() : text;
  var fragments = [
    text.substr(0, start),
    text.substr(start, end - start + 1),
    text.substr(end + 1, text.length)
  ];
  fragments[1] = replacement;
  return fragments.join('');
}
```

But, to satisfy the need you described (to replace the portion *after* the text between `a` and `b`):

```
function replaceAfterStringPortion(text, start, end, replacement, trim) {
  text = !!trim ? text.trim() : text;
  var fragments = [
    text.substr(0, start),
    text.substr(start, end - start + 1),
    text.substr(end + 1, text.length)
  ];
  fragments[2] = replacement;
  return fragments.join('');
}
```

---

## Secondly, `.substr()` and `.replace()` worked just fine. Here's why:

If you nest your expression command it may be more clear:

```
text = text.replace(
    text.substring(5,10), // Returns "Hello"
  "Something"
);
```

So really what you're doing, in this order:

1. `text.substring(5,10)` which returns `"Hello"`
2. `text.replace("Hello", "Something");` which, as expected, return `"SomethingHello"`

This is expected because `.replace()` replaces the first occurrence of the string or pattern you pass:

> `str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function)`
>
> ...
>
> **substr (pattern)**
>
> A String that is to be replaced by newSubStr. It is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular
>   expression. Only the first occurrence will be replaced.

- [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: Added `trim` option for whitespace padding